# Implement query to component in Jest with ReactQuery

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-typescript, react-query

I would like to test my component if it renders after receiving data from query.

Fetch function:

```
const fetchWeather = async (lat: number, lon: number) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${OW_API_URL}forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&${OWApiKey}`);
  const weather= await response.json();
  return weather;
};
```

Component:

```
const { data } = useQuery(
    ['weather'],
    () => fetchWeather(latitude, longitude),
);

return (
    <div>
      {data ? (<p>Data recieved</p>) : (<p>Data's empty</p>)}
    </div>
);
```

Test:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const componentProps = {
    latitude: 50,
    longitude: 50,
};

const wrapper = () => (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Weather latitude={componentProps.latitude} longitude={componentProps.latitude} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
);

const { result } = renderHook(() => fetchNextWeather(componentProps.latitude, componentProps.longitude), { wrapper });

await waitFor(() => result.current);

expect(result).toBe(true);
```

Error is:

```
- true"
+ "Object {
+   "current": null,
+ }"
```

Why result is null? What could be the reason?

I have used a test hook and error was this same, so it's probably some error about how to call a data.

```
function useCustomHook() {
    return useQuery({ queryKey: ['customHook'], queryFn: () => 'Hi' });
}
```

```
const { result } = renderHook(() => useCustomHook(), { wrapper });
await waitFor(() => result.current);
```

Comment: Have you done API testing with dummy data? Maybe some API Problem.

Comment: @Sanidhya this same fetch function works on component and its giving correctly data when I run an app. Its not about API.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

```
await waitFor(() => result.current);
```

`waitFor` only wait until the function doesn't **throw**. But your function never throws, it just returns `null` when there is no current result. You're not waiting for anything.

You could achieve that with:

```
await waitFor(() => {
    if (!result.current) {
        throw new Error('Not yet')
    }
});
```

```
expect(result).toBe(true);
```

This can never pass, because result will always be `{ current: something }`, maybe you want to assert as

```
expect(result.current).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Not working still. I am wondering right now it's there option to set useEffect refetch in component, then try to force useEffect in test, then component should refetch by himself and get data from api.